# jupyter kernel "not found" in ubuntu EC2 machine

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I'd really appreciate some help. I'm running jupyter notebook from my EC2 p2.xlarge ubuntu machine. I SSH into the server & try to launch jupyter notebook

`jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1`

I then access the jupyter notebook through my IPv4 Public IP, through HTTPS & using the session token that's provided to me by the server.

I can open jupyter notebook just fine. when I try to execute any notebooks I get a descriptive kernel error of **"Not Found"**.

when I list my kernels "jupyter kernelspec list" I get:

```
 python2    /home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
 python3    /home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I have tried activating them individually & running the notebook. 
I have tried uninstalling them & reinstalling them, pointing to the exact folder where each python version is installed in my ubuntu machine.

All to no avail.

Can someone please welp me?